# Determine if window is focused/Active/foreground

Tags: c++, window, focus

I'm working on a project that has multiple windows. 
I want to close the active window when I press enter.

The problem is that all the windows shut down. I want to check if the window is focused/active or on the foreground so that I can change the focus so it doesnt close all windows.

When I run the code I get all the time "I dont close". And after a while they all close.

```
if(GetFocus() == currentWindow->getHandler() || GetForegroundWindow() == currentWindow->getHandler() || GetActiveWindow() == currentWindow->getHandler() )
{                       
                std::cout << "Is the same";
                if(windows.front() != currentWindow)
                {
                    SetForegroundWindow(SetFocus(windows.front()->getHandler()));                                   
                    DeleteWindow(currentWindow)                     
                }
                else
                {
                    SetForegroundWindow(SetFocus(windows.back()->getHandler()));
                    DeleteWindow(currentWindow);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "I dont close!";
                DeleteWindow(currentWindow);
            }
            Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Do some debugging. Look at how the conditions in the out if evaluate. That will tell you why the "I don't close" branch is chosen. Obviously we cannot tell you that. And what is that call to `Sleep` for?

Comment: I used the debugging and the changing of the focused windows goes as i plannend but still all the windows closes. the sleep is so that i can monitor it properlly. Otherwise i get 50 changes a sec. In the DeleteWindow(currentWindow) i only say exit(1); Is there a beter way to close a window?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with an application like yours that had multiple windows. I found that GetForegroundWindow will always return the top-level parent window for an application instead of the actually-focused window. Also, according to MSDN, GetFocus and GetActiveWindow return NULL unless the calling thread has a message queue for the window (i.e. it owns the window). So, that may be why none of your checks work.

Have you tried [GetGUIThreadInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? The hwndFocus member holds the window that has keyboard focus. This function doesn't have any restrictions about calling threads or window ownership.